# Android Google Maps class not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to create a simple project where I can only add a simple project where I can only display a map, I will show you my problem in detail in the following code.

This is my Map.java code:

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Map" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/maps" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAqhSrLK9wFegbublRPJXKaHbDviXQSLyk" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And finally this is my error log:

```
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maps/com.example.maps.Map}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.maps.Map" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.maps.Map" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.maps-1.apk
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
11-05 11:21:59.252: E/AndroidRuntime(27109):    ... 11 more
```

Note that I have my google-play-services_lib added to my project. What am I doing wrong? 
As an IDE, I am using Eclipse with ADT.

Comment: your code seems to be fine, refresh clean and rebuild your project. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.
Try recopying the google-play-services_lib from C:/sdk and import the project.
Right click the project, click Android, check "Is library" and check the last available API you have installed, for example "Android 5.0 Android Open Source Project 5.0 API21".
This should fix your problem. It's a bit tricky to add that library though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try your XML File code like:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapDetailview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="210dip"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:text="MapView" />
```

,

Check Library File added successfully,

For Testing purpose wright variable

GoogleMap map; in your Map.java  class.

If Map class is available then clean your project and rebuild application again ,I think it should work.